# setGroupByInstances doesn't work when creating TestNG.xml programatically

Tags: testng

I use a separated class to create my testng.xml programatically. Everything works fine, except I can't add "group-by-instances" parameter to my tests. I tried to following code:

```
(...)
XmlSuite suite = new XmlSuite();
(...)
XmlTest test = new XmlTest(suite);
test.setName("sampleTest");
test.setGroupByInstances(true);
(...)
```

After that my testng.xml won't include that. So my question is, how can I add the mentioned parameter to my tests or is there any other solution for that?

Thanks in advance!

Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in testNG. Fixed in version 6.8.17.

[Github Commit - group-by-instances in toXml()](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/commit/cf3f9f7f67e95df3e7668a67ffaf00ffdaae1e4b)